# Python time always time at beginning of script?

Tags: datetime, python-2.5

Code I have written involves getting the time waiting for 10 minutes and then getting the time again, but in both cases `datetime.time(datetime.now())` returns the same time and in both cases the time is NOT the time when I ran the part to check the time, its the time that the entire script began to execute

(e.g. if the script starts at 7:05 and at 7:06 i check the time it will tell me its 7:05 etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I just realised what was happening, I had the `datetime.time(datetime.now())` being passed as the default argument to a method

```
def timeTo12Hour(time = datetime.time(datetime.now())):
    etc...
```

I believe it was getting evaluated at the beginning of the script rather than when I executed the method.